# Selecting a string without Space and without Number in the beginning

Tags: python, regex

Here is my string:

```
^((\S)([a-z]))[a-zA-Z0-9_+-.]+@[a-zA-Z.-]+\.(edu|com|edu7|org)$\b
```

I need to check for 2 conditions in the beginning of a string:

1. No space
2. No number

My string satisfies the first condition but fails the second condition.  Thank you for any suggestions.  I did try regex101 but could not solve it.

Here are two email addresses that are both invalid:

```
  somebody@gmail.com  
5somebody@gmail.com
```

I want neither of those returned by the program.  My current code considers the second email as valid, which is incorrect.

Comment: You probably just need `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_+.-]*@[a-zA-Z.-]+\.(?:edu|com|edu7|org)$`, if your string must start with a letter.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much.  One more question.  If I get a number at end, that should be invalid too. For example: somebody@gmail.com7

Comment: Your regex already covers that (only `edu7` ends in a digit), the string  can end only in `edu`, `com`, `edu7`, `org`. So, maybe all you need is remove `edu7`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected matches imply that you want to only allow letters as the first char in the string, so you can use

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_+.-]*@[a-zA-Z.-]+\.(?:edu7?|com|org)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xEsHph/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_+.-]*` - zero or more letters, digits, `_`, `+`, `.` and `-` (note the position of the hyphen, it must be at the end of the character class)
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[a-zA-Z.-]+` - one or more letters, dots or  hyphens
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:edu7?|com|org)` - `edu`, `edu7`, `com`, `org`
- `$` - end of string.